# Java Array index problem

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

cantmano is the index, it starts on 0. Another method increases with cant++.
I recheck that 0 <= cantmano <= 10

```
public void dibujar(){
    //actualiza la pantalla
    if (cantmano >= 0 && cantmano < 10 && cantcroupier >= 0 && cantcroupier < 10){
        TextView textomano = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        TextView textocroupier = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        CharSequence buffer = textomano.getText();

        textomano.setText( buffer + " " +
            String.valueOf(manojugador[cantmano].getPalo())+ " de " +
            String.valueOf(manojugador[cantmano].getNumero()) ); // <-- ERROR

        textocroupier.setText( String.valueOf(cantmano) );
    }
}
```

I get a nice

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.pruebas.blackjack.blackjack.dibujar(blackjack.java:58)
    at com.pruebas.blackjack.blackjack.onCreate(blackjack.java:23)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2717)
```

EDITS:
`.getNumero()` returns the int with the value of a requested CARD. (playing card type)
`.getPalo()` returns an int where 1= diamonds, etc.

initialization of manojugador:

```
Carta manojugador[]= new Carta[10];

constructor of Carta:

public Carta(){
    int palo=0;
    int numero=0;
}
```

MIDNIGHT UPDATE:
With some improvements i managed it to get over the error. BUT now the array has all 0 values when written. This has to be an easy to solve but that's the final step before accepting the best answer.

Here's the method that adds cards:

```
public void hit(View v){
        //sacan cartas
        if (cantmano < manojugador.length){
        manojugador[cantmano]=mazo.darcarta(); //adds a random Card to the manojugador. mazo means deck.
        manocroupier[cantcroupier]=mazo.darcarta(); //adds a random Card to the manojugador. mazo means deck.
        cantmano++;
        cantcroupier++;
        }
        dibujar();
    }
```

Comment: Can you println the value of (manojugador[cantmano]) before the problem line?

Comment: Que dice la linea 58 de blackjack.java  ?  `com.pruebas.blackjack.blackjack.dibujar(blackjack.java:58)`

Comment: Please post the code that initializes the `manojugador` array. I suspect it's not being initialized completely.

Comment: what does getNumero() do? and what does it return?

Comment: @OscarRyz: The OP has indicated what line the `NullPointerException` is thrown with the `// <-- ERROR` comment.

Comment: @OscarRyz: I understood your comment and I don't even speak the language! Pretty good, huh?

Comment: @Asaph And the credit is all mine for questioning in a *neutral* way... :)  I could have also asked: *Puedes revisar que dice la línea 58 de tu archivo?* :P :P

Comment: See the update! I knew it!! :)

Comment: @OscarRyz: But "la línea 58" and the OP's stacktrace is all I need to see to understand either comment.

Comment: @Asaph ok make it *.. lo que dice en el renglón cincuenta y ocho* jajaja

Comment: @OscarRyz: Well then I would simply use [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/#auto|en|lo%20que%20dice%20en%20el%20renglón%20cincuenta%20y%20ocho%20jajaja) which gives: "what it says on the line lol fifty-eight".

Comment: @Asaph Ohh yeah?? well try this: *"Vafamosfo afa verfe quefe dificefe esfetofo"*  ( ¬¬ I couldn't thought in a better way to  *"encode"* the message :P ) Safalufudosfo :)

Comment: @OscarRyz: You've even stumped Google Translate with that one :)

Comment: @Asaph hehehe that's similar to pig latin, but you just append `f[a-u]` to each syllable. For instance: `Hola Mundo` ( hello world ) , would be `HoFA-laFA MunFU-doFO` O>::)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `manojugador` array null elements and your `cantmano` is somehow pointing to one of those null elements.

For instance, let's say you have:

```
ManoJugador [] cantmano = new ManoJugador[10];

cantmano[0] = new ManoJugador();
cantmano[1] = new ManoJugador();
cantmano[2] = new ManoJugador();
```

You array beyond index 3 you have nulls. That's why when your try to get the numero of null you get NullPointerException.

**EDIT**

As per your edit:

Yeap, definitely, you have a null value there. Debug that part and you'll see some null values

hint: `System.out.println( java.util.Arrays.toString( someArray ));`

Suerte!

Comment: So do i have to loop trough cantmano[i] calling the constructor?

Comment: No no no, you have to either fill your array with valid values, or trim your array to the correct size.  I would also recommend you to use a `List<ManoJugador>` instead.

Comment: Other ( bad ) option would be to check if the element is null, but that's only a way to hide the underlaying problem.

Comment: Post that in the original code. Seems like you're leaving  empty slots. Perhaps the last one.

Comment: @alfa64 Definitivamente tienes algunos nulls en tu arreglo, revisa esa sección de tu código. Saludos.

Comment: I will try lists if this doesn't work. Saludos desde Argentina y viva Méjico!

Comment: Yeah do that.. although you may have some problems to change it all. Perhaps it would be better if you fill the array properly. Saludos a la Argentina tambien desde México!!! ;)

Answer (score 3):

You must initialize the array *and* it's elements. If you simply have this:

```
Carta manojugador[]= new Carta[10];
```

then all 10 elements of the array will be `null`. You must also initialize each element. Something like this:

```
for(int i=0, length=manojugador.length; i<length; i++) {
    manojugador[i] = new Carta();
}
```

### Update:

I see that in your `hit()` method, I see you have:

```
if (cantmano <= 8) {
```

Shouldn't that be:

```
if (cantmano < 10) {
```

Or even better:

```
if (cantmano < manojugador.length) {
```

I think that what is happening in your code to cause the `NullPointerException` is that `manojugador[9]` can never be initialized.

Comment: +1 just for conversation above. ( I don't intend to disregard you answer though )

Comment: @OscarRyz: I just upvoted your answer too. The conversation was fun for me too.